# Passing the corresponding data from one view to another on clicking link in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am stuck with how to pass data from one view to another.
I have a view named " Session" which displays data from db through foreach loop in table format.
Each row has a "add trainee" link. on its click it directs to another view.
I need to get all the details from the row of link to get displayed on redirected view.

I dont have any clue on how to implement it neither have any sample code.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Don't use a anchor tag for "add trainee".  Use a form that passes whatever identifier you are using for the row and post that.  In you post action get the data and show it in the next view.

Comment: Add the record id to the "add trainee" link as query parameter and reload the record in the next action. Remeber that the records can be changed by other users in the menatime so it is not safe to rely on the data from the previous view.

Comment: Are your row details (in the Session view) stored in the database? Hence, can you get the row data based on some id (Session id i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should use query string `<a href="/add-trainee?sessionid=123">Add trainee</a>`  [Add trainee](/add-trainee?sessionid=123)

while /add-trainee route to your TraineeController AddTrainee method

I add sample code

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class Session
    {
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Trainee> Trainees { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trainee
    {
        public int TraineeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class SessionController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Session
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Session> sessions = new List<Session>();
            sessions.Add(new Session { SessionId = 1, Name = "Session 1"});
            sessions.Add(new Session { SessionId = 1, Name = "Session 2" });
            sessions.Add(new Session { SessionId = 1, Name = "Session 3" });
            return View(sessions);
        }  
    }
}


namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class TraineeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Add(int sessionid)
        {
            List<Session> sessions = new List<Session>();
            sessions.Add(new Session { SessionId = 1, Name = "Session 1" });
            sessions.Add(new Session { SessionId = 1, Name = "Session 2" });
            sessions.Add(new Session { SessionId = 1, Name = "Session 3" });
            var session = sessions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SessionId == sessionid);
            ViewBag.session = session;
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Session Index (Index.cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Controllers.Session>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Sessions";
}

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
           <a href="/trainee/add?sessionid=@item.SessionId">Add Trainee</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Add Trainee view (Add.cshtml)

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.Trainee

@{
    var session = ViewBag.session;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Add Trainee</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Session Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">@session.Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are couple of approaches to do this.

1. pass the id to new view and get the detail data from database based on this id ,then display the detail.
2. get all the details from the row by javascript and store them in sessionstorage, then get this sessionstorage in another view and display all the detail.